# Проблема с переводом статистики проверяющего в очередях

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Наблюдается проблема с переводом статистики проверяющего в [очереди проверок описания меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/239740) и в [очереди предлагаемых правок вопросов и ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/215923):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> AGS17 has approved 438 edit suggestions and rejected 83 edit suggestions and improved 29 edit suggestions

перевод:
*AGS17 одобрил 438 правок, отклонил 83 правки и улучшил 29 правок*

**UPD:**
т.к. правки *предлагаются*, то более правильный перевод в сокращении:

*AGS17 одобрил 438, отклонил 83 и улучшил 29 предложенных правок*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подцепил 27 старых слетевших переводов.

> $UserName$ одобрил $ApprovalCount$, отклонил $RejectionCount$ и улучшил $ImprovementCount$ предлагаемую правку

и т.д. Здесь с переводом выкрутились, но в общем случае больше двух числительных в одном предложении - это зло, которое [надо устранить](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301810/339911).

Будет на сайте после пересбоки движка и некоторых телодвижений от сотрудников компании. Ждите.